# Prove that the set of points that make up the unit circle are uncountable

Tags: linear-algebra

My math teacher asked us to prove that the set of points that make up the unit circle are uncountable.

We are supposed to do this by "exhibiting" (not sure if this means it can be a proven through just a drawing or it needs to be a well described function) a function that is 1:1 and onto from [0,1) to the points that make up the unit circle.

It's due tomorrow and I can't seem to figure it out at all. Thanks!

Comment: At your stage¸‘exhibiting’ means constructing an explicit one-to-one and onto function, with as much explanatory detail as is necessary to convince the grader that you understand exactly what the function is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: there is an obvious bijection from the unit circle to the interval $[0,2\pi)$ using angles.

Comment: @Paula Why not $f(x)=4x$?

Comment: Wow ok that was silly. Thanks!